# Use AVG in SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have Field with name Flights hours and the values are:

Flight Hours:
 44+33    77+34     69+20    64+36    81+10    81+19     85+34

I need  the AVG for these value. the value display hours+minutes 
Can any one help?

Comment: So each of these values is a separate string record in your DataSet? Like: Record1 = `"44+33"`, Record2 = `"77+34"`, Record3 = `"69+20"` etc?

Comment: Also, I assume there can be single digit values on either side, like `"9+33"` or `"25+4"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these values appear in a particular field in your DataSet, each as a separate record (as per my comment), then I would use an expression like:

`=CStr(Floor(Avg((CInt(Left(Fields!FlightHours.Value,InStr(Fields!FlightHours.Value,"+")-1))*60) + CInt(Right(Fields!FlightHours.Value,Len(Fields!FlightHours.Value)-InStr(Fields!FlightHours.Value,"+"))))/60)) & "+" & CStr(Round(Avg((CInt(Left(Fields!FlightHours.Value,InStr(Fields!FlightHours.Value,"+")-1))*60) + CInt(Right(Fields!FlightHours.Value,Len(Fields!FlightHours.Value)-InStr(Fields!FlightHours.Value,"+")))) Mod 60))`

This takes your original values (i.e. `44+33`) and splits out the hours and minutes separately (based on the location of the `+` character, converts them to numeric integer values, then multiplies the hours by 60 and sums with the minutes to obtain a total number of minutes. We then average these values for the entire DataSet before reversing the process, splitting the averaged minute value out into it's constituent hours and minutes, before reformatting as a string in the form `[h]h+[m]m` as per the original values.

For your sample data, this gives a result of `72+1`, which I believe is correct.

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful to you.